# European Government Bonds correlations

Tags: government-debt

Why do European Government Bonds 10Yr (or at least some of them) have such a high level of correlation?

Comment: With each other?

Comment: This question could be greatly improved by specifying exactly which bonds you are talking about.

Comment: It's not obvious to me why this was closed as homework. There is nothing in the question to suggest it is a homework question.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is because they are denominated is Euros and their yields respond to the European Central Bank monetary policy decisions.